# Unnecessary newlines using function 'printf'

Tags: c, newline

When allocating Strings on the heap (with 'malloc'),
and initializing them with the standard input (using 'fgets),
an unnecessary newline appears between them when trying to print them (with 'printf' and %s formatting).
for example:

```
main()
{
    char *heap1;
    char *heap2;

    heap1=malloc(10);
    heap2=malloc(10);
    fgets(heap1,10,stdin);
    fgets(heap2,10,stdin);
    printf("%s%s",heap1,heap2);
}
```

with input "hi1\nhi2" produces "hi1\nhi2".
compiled using gcc 4.3.4 for Debian.

Comment: From the bait-shop: That the output is really `"hi1\nhi2\n"` is a good clue (notice your test case doesn't have an explicit newline).  Use arrays on the stack when you can (no need to malloc here); your life will be simpler.

Comment: On second thought, it's unlikely-but-possible you created a non-compliant text file for input that had a line without a terminating newline, and got the output exactly as reported.  In which case: don't do that!  All lines should be terminated with newlines. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fgets also reads the '\n' (newline) character. You should remove it if you don't want it to print like that.

```
heap1[strlen(heap1) - 1] = '\0';
```

after you read the contents of heap1.

Comment: If the input line is 9 characters of more in length, this will silently remove the last character from it.  It's better to use `strrchr()`.

Comment: True. Unless you're sure the length of the string won't cause that to happen, either use strrchr() or check if heap1[strlen(heap1) - 1] is actually a newline.

Answer (score 2):

### fgets returns the newline as part of the string.

See man 3 fgets. Specifically:

> fgets() reads in at most one less
>   than size characters from stream  and 
>   stores  them  into  the buffer pointed
>   to by s.  Reading stops after an
>   EOF or a newline.  **If a newline is
>   read, it is stored into the  buffer.**
>   A '\0' is stored after the last
>   character in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

fgets is probably appending the newline. Try trimming the string you get back from fgets.